# SAGE Math - Graphs too big when printing pdf

Tags: pdf, printing, resize, sage

I'm trying to print out a Sage Worksheet that I created recently. However, when trying to print out the pdf Sage generates for me, the graphs I created take up either a whole page or are too big to fit on a whole page. Is there any way I can resize these graphs to fit no more than half a page?

I've tried the command G.show(figsize=2), which works, but only after compiling on the Sage worksheet.

Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I should probably mention that I am using Sage cloud to create the document.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting (perhaps in a hidden cell)

```
sage.plot.graphics.Graphics.SHOW_OPTIONS['figsize']=2
```

at the top (or bottom) of your worksheet.  This should globally change these, once you have evaluated your cells again.

However, you are right that the size you create is the size you get.  I suppose that is a feature in some sense...

Comment: Hi kcrisman, thank you for your response. I just tried putting the line into my document, but it has not fixed the problem. I forgot to mention that I am using SageCloud -- if that makes any difference. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you'd have to evaluate it beforehand.  But I don't know if sagemathcloud has tweaked these options slightly - it does have some custom stuff for graphics somehow, but hopefully wouldn't have messed with this...